# Can anyone help me solve this Logistic Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A population $p$ obeys the Logistic model. It satisfies the equation 
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{3}{1000}p(13-p),p>0$$

Assume that $p(0)=2$, solve for $p(87)$.

I am having a tough time grasping the idea of how to solve for this. I have failed numerous times and would appreciate it greatly if someone could solve it so i can follow the steps on another example.

Comment: Thank you! is there any possible way of using the Logistic equation in the form of P=P(0)/(aP(0)+(1-aP(0))e^(-kt))

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Separation of Variables.

We have:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{p(13-p)}dp = \int \dfrac{3}{1300}dt$$

Solve this for $p(t)$ with an unknown constant, then use the initial condition, $p(0)=2$, and arrive at $p(t)$.

Then, use that equation to find $p(87)$.

**Spoiler**

> $$\large p(t) = \dfrac{26 e^{\frac{3 t}{100}}}{2 e^{\frac{3 t}{100}}+11}, p(87) = \dfrac{26 e^{261/100}}{2 e^{261/100}+11} = 9.25636$$